# node.js and mysql connection pool does not export

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am unable to export a pool connection in node.js. What I want is to get the connection from the pool from the db.js and use it and then release it after using it.

db.js

```
var mySQL = require('mysql');
    var pool  = mySQL.createPool({
        host: config.host,
        user: config.user,
        password: config.password,
        database: config.database
    });
    var getConnection = function() {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if(err) throw err;
            return connection;
        });
    };
    module.exports.pool = getConnection;
```

query.js

```
var dbSql = require('./db');
var userQuery = 'select * from user';
var con = dbSql.pool();
console.log("con: " + con); //displays undefined
con.query(userQuery,function(err,user){
   con.release();
})
```

above when I do console.log("con: " + con); it displays undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are exporting a function, not the pool itself. Besides, getConnection is not accepting any callback:

db.js should be something like this:

```
var mySQL = require('mysql');
var pool  = mySQL.createPool({
    host: config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database
});
var getConnection = function (cb) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        //if(err) throw err;
        //pass the error to the cb instead of throwing it
        if(err) {
          return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, connection);
    });
};
module.exports = getConnection;
```

query.js should be something like this:

```
var getConnection = require('./db');
getConnection(function (err, con) {
  if(err) { /* handle your error here */ }
  var userQuery = 'select * from user';
  console.log("con: " + con); //displays undefined
  con.query(userQuery,function(err,user){
  con.release();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this is a better approach to handle the connection?

Comment: One question. In this way are we sharing a single connection?

Comment: @Java_NewBie they arent the same connection, unless ```pool.getConnection``` returns always the same connection. db.js doesn't export a connection but a function to get a connection

Comment: Thankyou. It is good to use the different connections or only the one connection? I think different connection are also good enough because at the end we are also releasing that used connection so that connection can be resused. right?

Comment: I guess it depends on your use case, DB size, queries you do, number of connections...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is your understanding of how callbacks and asychronous calls work in JavaScript and Node.js.

To understand the concept check [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm)

You will have to change your code to something like this:

db.js

```
var mySQL = require('mysql');
var pool  = mySQL.createPool({
    host: config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database
});
module.exports.pool = pool.getConnection; // export the pools getConnection
```

query.js

```
var dbSql = require('./db');
var userQuery = 'select * from user';
dbSql.pool(function(err, con) { // the function is called when you have a connection
    if(err) throw err; // or handle it differently than throwing it
    console.log("con: " + con); // not undefined anymore
    con.query(userQuery,function(err,user){
        con.release();
    }) 
});
```