# Bluebird, node-mysql, pooling, and disposing

Tags: node.js, bluebird, node-mysql

Currently trying to implement a different approach to connecting to my database using promises and pooling. This is what I have as of the moment:

```
// databaseConnection.js
var configDB = require('./database.js');
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool(configDB.connectionData);

function getSqlConnection() {
    return pool.getConnection(configDB.connectionData).disposer(function(connection) {
        connection.release();
    });
}

module.exports = getSqlConnection;
```

Then I use the query like this:

```
#sqlQuery.js
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var getSqlConnection = require('./databaseConnection')
Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function(connection) {
    return connection.query("SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE").then(function(row) {
        return process(rows);
    }
}
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/lukeb-uk/node-promise-mysql) library which is just `node-mysql` wrapped with BlueBird promises. With that, I wanted to take advantage of BlueBird's `disposing` and `using` capability so I would only be connected to the DB when I needed to be.

Currently though I'm getting an error from `Connection.js` of mysql stating: `cb is not a function`. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914736/node-js-and-mysql-connection-pool-does-not-export) question I have somewhat of an idea of what I'm doing wrong but I'm not sure how I would go about using that with BlueBird's dispose/using paradigm. Thanks in advance for anyone that can help!

Comment: In your `sqlQuery.js` code you are calling `getSqlConnection()` - without passing the `cb` (callback?) argument. What is this `cb` used for?

Comment: Sorry about that. I copied that code from my modified source. What's up there now should be the original. I don't use a callback in my code. Nor does it mention requiring one in the `node-mysql` documentation

Comment: OK, now since you do not have `cb` there anymore - are you still getting the same error message?

Comment: That is correct. Even more curious I just found this BlueBird example that seems to resemble mine: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/working-with-callbacks.md#mysql

Comment: Just figured it out. Going to post an answer. One moment

Answer (score 0):

Huge lack of oversight on my part. The following line:

`return pool.getConnection(configDB.connectionData).disposer...`

should be:

`return pool.getConnection().disposer...`

Sorry about that. Still getting an error for `connection.release` not being a function which is strange but at least I can move forward with debugging that.

Comment: Just to confirm - so you say even this did not help?

Comment: It did help. Just getting a different error now. Researching a possible fix at the moment

Comment: Try changing from `getConnection()`... and rather use `getConnectionAsync().disposer...`, see if this helps clear the error.

Comment: `getConnectionAsync()` isn't available in `node-mysql` pools from what I can tell

Comment: I was looking at [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797314/how-will-a-promisified-mysql-module-work-with-nodejs).

Comment: Appreciate the help! And yeah. Stumbled upon a similar post. Looking like I'm going to move away from using `node-promise-mysql` and just manually bluebirdify mysql